# I'm getting this error in the console "Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`."

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I don't know what's going on with this error. There is a similar question posted about this but it's using ES6, so it's too different for me to compare. I'm just trying to execute a simple route after the user logs in, but this error is thrown in the console and thus the router isn't working.

**index.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Routes = require('./routes.jsx');


ReactDOM.render(Routes, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

**routes.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var App = require('./components/app.jsx');
var Login = require('./components/login.jsx');

module.exports = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Login}>
      <Route path="app/" component={App} />
    </Route>  
  </Router>
)
```

**login.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var UserStore = require('../stores/user-store.jsx');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Link = Router.Link;

module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            userEmail: "",
            userPassword: ""     
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div className="row panel panel-default">
          <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h2 className="text-center">
                To-Do-List-Login
            </h2>
                <div className="input-group">
                  <span>Email</span>
                    <input 
                        value={this.state.userEmail}
                        onChange={this.handleUserEmail} 
                        type="text" 
                        className="form-control" />
                  <span>Password</span>
                    <input 
                        value={this.state.userPassword}
                        onChange={this.handleUserPassword} 
                        type="text" 
                        className="form-control" />
                  <span className="input-group-btn">
                    <Link onClick={this.handleCreate} to="app/" className="navbar-brand">Create User</Link>
                    <Link onClick={this.handleLogin} to="app/" className="navbar-brand">Login</Link>
                  </span>
                </div>
              <hr />
              {this.props.children}
           </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Version of react-router? Before 1.x the prop was called `handler` instead of `component`.

Comment: "react-router": "^1.0.0-beta2", so what exactly should I change?

Comment: Are you sure that that's the one that's installed?

Comment: I just did another npm install --save, the dependency in my package.json reads as I listed above: "react-router": "^1.0.0-beta2". Is there a command to check the specific version that is installed?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an outdated version of React Router. Use v1.0.3 if you want to use the latest stable release.